# mysqlで外部接続可能root@%にするとcreateができない

Tags: mysql

mysqlで外部接続可能root@%にするとcreateができません

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.shop TO root @’%‘
```

権限付与

```sql
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO 'root '@'%' identified by 'root';
```

です

Comment: create文ができませんとありますが、もっと具体的に記述してください。「接続ができない」、「コマンドを実行するとエラーになる」等。

Comment: root@%を作成したときのSQLおよび権限（Grant文）設定のSQL。Create実行時のコマンドおよびSQL文も記載してください。

Answer (score 0):

質問に書かれた通りに実行したのであれば、ユーザー名と `@` の間に余計な半角が入っているのが原因ではないでしょうか？

**あなたが実行したコマンド:**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.shop TO root @’%‘
```

**本来実行すべきコマンド:**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.shop TO root@’%‘
```

エラーメッセージでも以下の通り `'root '` として空白を含むユーザー名を指定したものとして弾かれているように見えます。

```
... TO 'root '@'%'
```

Comment: スペースを抜いてもおなじ結果です

Answer (score 0):

あとから権限を与えたらできました

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.shop TO root @’%‘
本来実行すべきコマンド:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.shop TO root@’%‘